# Prove $\int_{0}^{2} e^{x^2-x}dx \in [2e^{\frac{-1}{4}}, 2e^2]$

Tags: real-analysis

I based on intuition, what integral actually is, (very simply, i mean area under the graph) so first I drew a $e^{x^2-x}$ graph. $e^{x^2}$ is even function and $e^{x^2-x}$ was made by shifting the even function. $e^{x^2-x}$ is a continuous function, so it has an antiderivative. $\int_{0}^{2} e^{x^2-x}dx=G(2)-G(0)$. So
$$G'(x)=e^{x^2-x}$$

The minimum: $x=\frac{1}{2}$

So $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is the axis of symmetry of this function - am gonna use theorem, that when we consider even function, $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=\int_{-a}^{0}f(x)dx$ holds. So from this equation:
$$\int_{0}^{2}e^{x^2-x}dx=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}e^{x^2-x}dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{x^2-x}dx$$

I get

$$\int_{0}^{2}e^{x^2-x}dx=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2}e^{x^2-x}dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}e^{x^2-x}dx$$

More specifically, i need

$$\int_{\frac{1}{2a}}^{2a}e^{x^2-x}dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2a}}^{a}e^{x^2-x}dx$$

to avoid calculating $e^{x^2-x}$ - it seems very tough

$$2G'(2a)+\frac{1}{2a^2} G'\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)-G'(a)+\frac{1}{2a^2}G'\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)$$

Let $a=1$

$$2G'(2a)+\frac{1}{2a^2} G'\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)-G'(a)+\frac{1}{2a^2}G'\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)=2e^2+e^{\frac{-1}{4}}-1$$

But $2e^2+e^{\frac{-1}{4}}-1\in [2e^{\frac{-1}{4}}, 2e^2]$

Am I right?

Comment: $x^2-x=(x-1/2)^2-1/4.$ The minimal value is attained at $x=1/2$ and is equal $1/4.$ The maximal value is attained at $x=2$ and is equal $2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interval $[2e^{\frac{-1}{4}}, 2e^2]$ is too long since brute force gives
$\int_{0}^{2} e^{x^2-x}dx\approx3.588792$ and $2e^{-1/4}\approx1.557601$, $2e^2\approx14.718712$. In fact we have $$3\lt\int_{0}^{2} e^{x^2-x}dx\lt4$$ Such as given the problem, we have by convexity
$$\int_{0}^{2} e^{x^2-x}dx\le\text { area of T}$$ where $T$ is the trapezoide of vertex $(0,0),(0,1),(2,0),(2,7.389056)$ whose area is $f(0)+f(2)\approx8.389056\in[2e^{\frac{-1}{4}}, 2e^2]$

We are done.